# Flutter problem: How to fix Text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### Iwant to fix "Event" text of below code in First Screen shot.

Iwant to fix "Event" text of below code in First Screen shot.
This is my event.dart page

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/card_top.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/activities.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_page_changer.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/components/search_components.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  const Event({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}

class _EventState extends State<Event> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 210,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff80CAD7),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/bg_dummy.png'),   // background image
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 12, 0, 0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child:
                            Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 125, 18, 0),
              child: TabTop(
                onDataUpdated: () => setState(() {}),          // search section
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 190),
              child: Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Activities()),               //ListView slider
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        },
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        child: Image.asset('assets/btnavico.png'),
        elevation: 5.0,
        highlightElevation: 10,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (10 / 100),
          child: BottomNavBarEvent()),
    );
  }
}
```

Activity.dart page

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Activities extends StatelessWidget {
  const Activities({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: eventsUpcomingListData == "N"
          ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
          : ScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: eventsUpcomingListData.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          eventsUpcomingListData == "N"
              ? Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18,
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.7, 18, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Sorry, we couldn't find any results",
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: tSize18,
                              color: Color(0xFF444444)),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : EventListCard(eventsListData: eventsUpcomingListData[index]),
    );
  }
}
```

In actuall I want Like this ,I want to fix "Events" text none scrollabe and bellow list should be scrollabe

[image]

This time is looking like this
[image]

Comment: Just exit and relaunch your app hope its help

Comment: I can't seem to find the "Events" Text widget in your code. Where is it?